# Bad Interpreter No Such File or Directory - Docker Sync

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to start my Docker container and sync it up using Debian, I consistently encounter this error message after entering in "docker-sync-stack start"...

-bash: /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/docker-sync: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I'm fairly sure this is a path issue, but I can't seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not have Ruby installed on your system. That sometimes happens after a system upgrade.

There have been discussions about this

- here: https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/issues/683
- here: https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/issues/679

In general your system cannot find ruby, or your system (with the current ruby version used) cannot find the docker-sync plugin. So you need to [reinstall the plugin](https://docker-sync.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/installation.html) then.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me also after updating to Catalina. Fixed by running `brew reinstall ruby` and `brew reinstall docker-sync`.